# Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 createBucket signature calculated does not match

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

When trying to createBucket or createObject

I get the following response:

```
object(Zend_Http_Response)#13 (5) {
["version":protected] => string(3) "1.1"
["code":protected] => int(403)
["message":protected] => string(9) "Forbidden"
["headers":protected] => array(6) {
["X-amz-request-id"] => string(16) "XXX"
["X-amz-id-2"] => string(64) "XXX"
["Content-type"] => string(15) "application/xml"
["Transfer-encoding"] => string(7) "chunked"
["Date"] => string(29) "Mon, 09 Jul 2012 21:45:45 GMT"
["Server"] => string(8) "AmazonS3"
}
["body":protected] => string(875) "35f
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated   does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 0a 4d 6f 6e 2c 20 30 39 20 4a 75 6c 20 32 30 31 32 20 32 31 3a 34 35 3a 34 35 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 2f 65 64 75 70 72 6f 74 6f 6e 64 62 2f</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>XXXX</RequestId><HostId>XXX</HostId><SignatureProvided>XXX</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>PUT

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Mon, 09 Jul 2012 21:45:45 +0000 
/eduprotondb/</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId>XXXAWSAccessKeyId></Error>
0
"
}
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong since  getBuckets, deleteBuckets works just fine?

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($access_key, $secret_key, $region);
$s3->createBucket('eduprotondb');
```

Comment: @quickshiftin Since it is possible to delete a bucket and it is not possible to create one, it can't be an issue with the Bucket ACL. Maybe a couple of odd policies is set up for that bucket. Slik, are you able to use a third-party tool, like [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/) and try to create/delete buckets from there?

Comment: Yes, I tried Transmit & amazons own s3 browser, and I have no problem creating buckets & objects.

Comment: I have seen this error happen in a couple of scenarios. Two questions: At which region are you trying to create the bucket? Does this bucket already exist? Also, take a look into [this similar issue](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/issues/28#issuecomment-5723770).

Comment: I am actually passing null for region. I removed $region just in case this may be the problem. The default region should be chosen, which is normall us-east? No the bucket does not exists, I tested with Zend, had no luck then I used transmit to create the bucket which was successful. I guess I need to check with the zend community.

Answer (score 0):

Add the amazon S3 region you are using as the "location" parameter in the function. I just had the same problem and this fixed it!

```
$s3->createBucket($bucket, "us-west-1");
```